# aws ec2 project not accessible from the GoDaddy domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

My Problem is as below.

1. I have a domain registered with GoDaddy [ assume : mytest.com ]
2. I have a EC2 Ubuntu instance at AWS
3. I have elastic IP associated with my Instance [ assume : 172.31.34.24]
4. I have developed a Django application and deployed in instance
5. That Django application is running at port 80
6. Application is accessible using http://172.31.34.24/
7. I have created hosted Zone at route53 and the  4 unique nameservers i have added to GoDaddy dns nameservers.
   8)Created record with ip  [ assume : 172.31.34.24]
   9)and I also have "soa" record
   now my project is not accessible from the domain [ assume : mytest.com ]
   Which step am I forgetting ??
   please help

Comment: "Which step am I forgetting". 2 of them: 1) give the real names and even more important 2) post in appropriate place, which is not here as your question is not related to programming which is the topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have done everything correctly there are few considerations:

- Updating NS records on GoDaddy is NOT instant
- SOA record is not required in your case (nor any information given as to why)
- Test if you have set A record for the IP address
- Verify the domain values with mxtoolbox.com

Comment: it takes 48 hours to reflect the project to domain my project is live now after two days